# File System Events API causing Finder to lock up?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, dropbox, fsevents

I'm using Apple's File System Events API to monitor a directory hierarchy. I'm essentially using the [example from Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html) verbatim, so I won't post my code unless somebody asks for it. My callback adds modified paths to a queue, which is processed in a background `NSOperationQueue`.

As far as my app is concerned, all is working fine. It gets all expected events, handles them, and goes back to business.

Finder, on the other hand, flips out while my app is running. It's constant 10-15 second spinning wheels of death (with normal behavior between them). When my app exits, or I comment out the call to `FSEventStreamStart`, Finder is fine.

A potential complication is that the directories I am monitoring are under Dropbox, so I assume the Dropbox daemon is also monitoring this directory in a similar fashion. Am I interfering with its behavior somehow?

How can I tell what's going on here?

Comment: If you sample Finder while it is hung, what does the sample say?

Comment: I tried to check, but the problem has suddenly disappeared on its own. If (when) it comes back, I'll try this.

Comment: This still hasn't returned, so I'm chalking it up to random weirdness until I see it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stopped happening several days ago, and never started again. So I'm chalking it up to random weirdness until I see it again.